# Insert NULL value from xml to database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

How can I insert null value from XML string to database.

When I insert, Then DOB field inserted '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' and Gender Field''.
I want to insert NULL value to this column. Please help me.

```
<Child>
  <EnrolmentNo>01113702010</EnrolmentNo>
  <Name>Ankush</Name>
  <DOB></DOB>
  <Email>Anushka@gmail.com</Email>
  <Gender></Gender>
  <Phone>9990234323, 9452344321</Phone>
  <RegistrationDate>2013-11-12T00:00:00</RegistrationDate>
  <ValidUpto>2014-12-12T00:00:00</ValidUpto>
</Child>

@Input    XML 
INSERT INTO KP_StudentsTemp  
(    
[EnrolmentNo],[SessionId],[BatchId],[SemesterId],  
[FirstName],[MiddleName],[LastName],[DOB],[Email],[Gender],[Phone],  
[RegistrationDate],[ValidUpto]
)
SELECT (XNodes.value('(EnrolmentNo)[1]','varchar(32)')),
XNodes.value('(Name)[1]','varchar(32)'),   
XNodes.value('(DOB)[1]','datetime'),  
XNodes.value('(Email)[1]','varchar(256)'),    
XNodes.value('(Gender)[1]','char(1)'),  
XNodes.value('(Phone)[1]','varchar(64)'),  
XNodes.value('(RegistrationDate)[1]','datetime'),  
XNodes.value('(ValidUpto)[1]','datetime')
FROM @input.nodes('/Main/Child') AS XTbl(XNodes)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `NULLIF` function

```
@Input    XML 
INSERT INTO KP_StudentsTemp  
(    
[EnrolmentNo],[SessionId],[BatchId],[SemesterId],  
[FirstName],[MiddleName],[LastName],[DOB],[Email],[Gender],[Phone],  
[RegistrationDate],[ValidUpto]
)
SELECT (
XNodes.value('(EnrolmentNo)[1]','varchar(32)')),
XNodes.value('(Name)[1]','varchar(32)'),   
NULLIF(XNodes.value('(DOB)[1]','datetime'),'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'),  
XNodes.value('(Email)[1]','varchar(256)'),    
NULLIF(XNodes.value('(Gender)[1]','char(1)'),''),  
XNodes.value('(Phone)[1]','varchar(64)'),  
XNodes.value('(RegistrationDate)[1]','datetime'),  
XNodes.value('(ValidUpto)[1]','datetime')
FROM @input.nodes('/Main/Child') AS XTbl(XNodes)
```

## [NULLIF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)